# $.ajax not working with IE and working fine with Mozilla

Tags: jquery, client-side-scripting

i have a following code which runs fine with Mozilla but give object undefined error
when run on IE

here is the code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#button").click(function () {

               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                       xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
                     "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                   },
                   data: "{'customerid':" + "'" + $("#check").val + "'}",
                   url: "ajaxcall.aspx/checkval",
                   success: function (data) {
                       var c = data.d;
                       alert("success");
                       $("#result").html("day:" + c.seconds);
                   }
               });


           });
       });
```

now i have changed my server side c# code inside 
checkval function using json serialzation

```
Mydate md = new Mydate();
        md.day = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();
        md.month = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
        md.year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
        md.seconds = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
       return js.Serialize(md);
```

Now code is working in IE but only showing the string  as

> {"month":"10","year":"2011","day":"13","seconds":"44"}
>   and not working with Mozilaa
>
> in place of c.seconds if i write c only 
>   in this code
>
> $("#result").html("day:" + c.seconds);

it works for all browsers but the result is

> {"month":"10","year":"2011","day":"13","seconds":"44"}

Still not getting what i need

here is the answer atlast i got it
in place of this

```
                   var c = data.d;
                   alert("success");
                   $("#result").html("day:" + c.seconds);
```

Write

```
                   var mydata = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                   $("#result").html(mydata.seconds);
```

> this will work in IE and Mozilla both

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a small typo in `data`: `"{'customerid':" + "'" + $("#check").val + "'}"`.

Have you tried `$("#check").val()`?

Comment: Tried But not Working with IE